# 'error: expected expression before '{' token' - matrix as member of struct

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d

I'm fairly new to C (think a month of experience), so today, for some practice, I've been working on a matrix/vector calculator. I've tried Googling and Stackoverflowing (as well as looking at some Github repos), but I'm at wit's end. The error in the title - **'error: expected expression before '{' token'** - occurs at **dataSetA.matrix = {...}** in the code in **calc.c**

From what I read, I can't declare and initialise an array that way; I tried re-declaring it all differently (rMatrix dataSetA[3][3] = {...}), but to no avail.

**calc.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "matrix.c"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

  // Set up sample rotation matrix
  rMatrix dataSetA;
  dataSetA.nRows = 3;
  dataSetA.mCols = 3;
  dataSetA.matrix = {
    {0.171822648222828f, 0.313110361222276f, -0.934044366854675f},
    {0.134340268046073f, 0.931840597647996f, 0.337084252014737f},
    {0.975925032950279f, -0.183398479465564f, 0.118047989354818f}
  };

...
```

Here's the struct definition for rMatrix:

```
typedef struct rotationMatrix
{
  int nRows;
  int mCols;
  float** matrix;
} rMatrix;
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The same question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608511/initializing-an-array-of-pointers-to-pointers).

Comment: Including other `.c` files should be avoided. If you want to have one struct definition that is used by multiple `.c` files, then place it in a `.h` file and include that from both `.c` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rMatrix` type is a variable size matrix.  You cannot initialize the `matrix` member from the static initializer you would use for an fixed size 2d array.  You need to allocate the array, either from the heap or as an automatic array and initialize it *by hand*, one element at a time:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Set up sample rotation matrix
    float values[3][3] = {
        {0.171822648222828f, 0.313110361222276f, -0.934044366854675f},
        {0.134340268046073f, 0.931840597647996f, 0.337084252014737f},
        {0.975925032950279f, -0.183398479465564f, 0.118047989354818f} };
    rMatrix dataSetA;
    dataSetA.nRows = 3;
    dataSetA.mCols = 3;
    dataSetA.matrix = malloc(3 * sizeof(*dataSetA.matrix));
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        dataSetA.matrix[row] = malloc(3 * sizeof(**dataSetA.matrix));
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            dataSetA.matrix[row][col] = values[row][col];
        }
    }
    // your code here
}
```

This is very cumbersome.  If your rotation matrices have a fixed 3x3 size, you can simplify this code considerably.

Answer (score 0):

C Doesn't work that way, you need to allocate memory for the matrix, or predefine it to be array of arrays, otherwise, your matrix is just a pointer to a pointer to a point array - as experiment - do sizeof(dataSetA.matrix) and see what you get.

Protip: It wont be float * mRows * nCols.

Either this (Stack allocation):

```
typedef struct rotationMatrix
{
  int nRows;
  int mCols;
  float matrix[M][N];
} rMatrix;
```

or this (Heap allocation):

```
  rMatrix dataSetA;
  dataSetA.nRows = 3;
  dataSetA.mCols = 3;
  dataSetA.matrix = malloc(sizeof(float *)*dataSetA.nRows);
  for (int i = 0; i < dataSetA.nRows ;i++) { dataSetA.matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(float)*dataSetA.mCols); }
```

Either way, memory must be allocated either at compile time (i.e - Stack variable), or at Runtime (i.e - Heap Variable)

Judging by how your struct looks, you're looking for a heap allocation.

Things to remember while using heap allocation:

Malloc can fail, always check that return value isn't NULL.

free() must be used on all allocated memory when finished in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Actually, since you use arguments `mCols` and `nRows`, you should use them to initialize the corresponding members of `dataSetA`.

Comment: @chqrlie, I don't really understand, what are you referring to?

Comment: You use variables named `mCols` and `nRows` that aren't defined anywhere.  Either use `dataSetA.nRows` and `dataSetA.mCols` in the `malloc` size calculation or show the definition of these parameters and use them to initialize `dataSetA.nRows` and `dataSetA.mCols`.

Comment: Both your answers seemed to work (this one needed nRows to be set to dataSetA's members), at least the compiler doesn't complain anymore. But now the application hangs when I try to launch it; however, I'm grateful. I come from a Python/Javascript background, so pointers and memory allocation are alien to me.